# YouTube integration with a website

Tags: youtube

I want to integrate YouTube (a channel for example) on my website, e.g. http://www.sensation.com/world/en/video.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/overview.html

Especially the [Data API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/getting_started.html).